# How to avoid generating unexpected fields with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

define a POJO as below with @Data

```
@Data
public class Student{
  private String userName;
  private String id;

  public boolean isGood(){ return true;} 

}
```

Convert to JSON, the response would be

```
{
  "userName" : "xxx",
  "id" : "1234",
  "good" : true
}
```

My question is how to avoid generating the extra property "good" with lombok? BTW, the version of lombok I use is 1.16.18.

Comment: It's not about lombok, it's about your json framework. It use getter/setter to detect the bean's properties.

Comment: Hi, what's JSON library are you using? And version of it?

Comment: I have solved this issue. Yes , it's nothing with lombok, but the HTTPMessageConverter. I used @JsonIgnore to annotate the method, then the "good" disappeared. But I still don't know why this happens.